# How to Extract response header value in postman?

Tags: postman

How can I fetch the value of a response header in postman and save it in a variable so that I can use it in the next request?

Example:

> HeaderName: HeaderValue
> AESKey:     ndowijdw92n9992n

I need to fetch `ndowijdw92n9992n` and send it to the next request.

Answer (score 9):

There is more direct way to access `AESKey` header:

```
const responseHeaderAESKey = pm.response.headers.get("AESKey");
pm.environment.set("AESKey", responseHeaderAESKey );
```

Now the environment variable set contains the AESKey and you can access it in any part of Postman request with `{{AESKey}}`. So use it in the next request.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the response headers using `pm.response.headers`. Try placing the below code in test tab of the request which writes the response header value of 'HeaderValue' to the environments and you can access the variable value in next requests. Refer [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/).

```
var reponseHeaders = pm.response.headers.all();
reponseHeaders.forEach(function(header){
    if(header.key == "HeaderValue"){
        pm.environment.set("Key", header.value)
        return;
    }    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

@Srđan Popić has provided the correct answer and explanation, however with that I would like to add condition to check the response first, just to avoid unnecessary execution of the actual code:

```
if(pm.response.code === 200) {
    pm.environment.set('token', pm.response.headers.get("AESKey"))
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?